# Add a Foreign Key to an Existing Table that Contains what would be Invalid FK Values (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

**I need to add a Foreign Key to a table that already exists and is populated with data that would contain invalid Foreign Key Values. (MYSQL)**
*I know there are several questions along these lines, but I can't seem to find any that answer my scenario.*

**Table and Data Structure**
"GblTable" contains an "Org" field that needs to become a FK of the Org table.  The Org table has a PK field called "number".

Currently, the GblTable contains non-existent Org numbers (ie. If the Org table has rows with PKs 1,2, and 3, GblTable might have rows with Org as 4 or 5).  While this is the case, I cannot apply the constraint to reference GblTable.org to Org.number.

I believe the best approach for this particular situation will will be to set the FK field in those rows to NULL before I apply the constraint.  NULL is a valid GblTable.Org value for the program, so this would achieve an acceptable outcome.

**What I Have so Far**
I want to set all GblTable.Org values to NULL where they do not match a valid Org.Number.

In pseudocode:

```
set GblTable.ORG to NULL 
    where the GblTable.number is one of the following:
    (  select all GblTable.numbers where the GblTable.Org does not match an existing Org.Number )
```

In Sql, but I get the error "You can't specify target table 'GblTable' for update in FROM clause":

```
update GblTable set Org=NULL
    where number IN (
        select number
        from   GblTable
        where  Org NOT IN (select number from Org)
        )
```

**What's the best way to achieve my requirement?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the extra level of subquery:

```
update GblTable set Org=NULL
    where  Org NOT IN (select number from Org)
```

Comment: Thank you TheVedge.  I don't know why I was overcomplicating my query...
 
I have to wait 8 more minutes to accept the answer, which I will do.

Comment: This will work, but `NOT EXISTS` is usually faster, sometimes a lot faster depending on the size of the Org table and the version of MySQL you are using. For example: `update GblTable set Org=NULL where not exists (select null from Org where Org.number = GblTable.Org)`